# How set a setting with #+OPTIONS to a list as argument?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Well, my desired behavior is to set this:

```
#+OPTIONS: tasks:(DONE IN-PROGRESS)
```

To export the tasks with these keywords, however I think I don't understand well how the syntax for list looks like. So setting this way doesn't works. I can set `tasks:done` to export the `DONE` tasks, but the IN-PROGRESS is useful to include for testing. (I'm writing notes on org-mode to export to LaTeX -> PDF). I can set too `tasks:t`, but I don't want TODO items.

On emacs internal documentation of org-mode I saw that:

```
org-export-with-tasks is a variable defined in ‘ox.el’.
Its value is t

Documentation:
Non-nil means include TODO items for export.

This may have the following values:
t                    include tasks independent of state.
‘todo’               include only tasks that are not yet done.
‘done’               include only tasks that are already done.
nil                  ignore all tasks.
list of keywords     include tasks with these keywords.

This option can also be set with the OPTIONS keyword,
e.g. "tasks:nil".

You can customize this variable.
```

And the official documentation of [`org-mode Export Settings`](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html) I read that:

> tasks:
>   Toggle inclusion of tasks (TODO items); or nil to remove all tasks; or todo to remove DONE tasks; or list the keywords to keep (org-export-with-tasks).

But I still don't have a clue how set the setting `tasks` as a list argument. Seems I'm losing something fundamental here. Thanks for any guidance here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todo keywords are strings so they need quotes around them:

```
#+OPTIONS: tasks:("DONE" "IN-PROGRESS")
```

Comment: Yes, I knew that I was losing something fundamental. Fixed gracefully. Thanks.