# org-export ignoring done entries

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is it possible to have org-mode export ignore entries that are in a completed state (e.g., DONE, WONTFIX).

Note that I do not want to create a sparse tree and then export what's visible, that will not necessarily give the same result.

Comment: See this question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35358/how-set-a-setting-with-options-to-a-list-as-argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(setq org-export-with-tasks 'todo)
```

As from description of variable, it can be placed as file local variable. Or you could include at in the `#+OPTIONS` line: `tasks:todo`, and you would get ignored DONE tasks by export. Review other options for this variable as well.

```
This may have the following values:
t                    include tasks independent of state.
‘todo’               include only tasks that are not yet done.
‘done’               include only tasks that are already done.
nil                  ignore all tasks.
list of keywords     include tasks with these keywords.

This option can also be set with the OPTIONS keyword,
e.g. "tasks:nil".
```

You can try this on following example:

```
#+TITLE: New title
#+TODO: TODO(t) WAIT(w) SCHD(s) DEFR(r) PROJ(j) | DONE(d) WONT(x) SDAY(m) FAIL(f)

* DEFR First
* SDAY Second is done
  CLOSED: [2019-07-18 Do 04:13]
* SDAY PENDING This is pending
  CLOSED: [2019-07-18 Do 04:18]
* PROJ CANCELED This is canceled
```

Which gives following output:

```
                  ____________

                   NEW TITLE

                   Jean Louis
                  ____________


Table of Contents
_________________

1. DEFR First
2. PROJ CANCELED This is canceled





1 DEFR First
============


2 PROJ CANCELED This is canceled
================================
```

Comment: Should be `(setq org-export-with-tasks 'todo)`, but otherwise points in the right direction.

Comment: What about headings without todo keywords?

Comment: ah that is what is target, than I corrected it, thank you for pointing

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: What @DoMiNeLa10 said. Please say how this answers the question.

Comment: The question is how to ignore entries on export that are in completed state. Setting that variable is exporting only those which are in TODO state.

Comment: I can see if I use tasks:todo option that headings without state are exported, but those which are done are not exported. Setting this variable is to help the person who asked for it in that particular case.

Comment: This worked almost perfectly, except that it ignores only `DONE` entries, but not other "completed" states. I have this option: `#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(t) WAIT(w) SCHD(s) DEFR(r) PROJ(j) | DONE(d) WONT(x) SDAY(m) FAIL(f)`. I would expect things to be in the `SDAY` state to be ignored by export, but they are ignored only when I change the headline to `DONE`.

Comment: I use it in the above updated example and it works, SDAY entries are ignored.

Comment: Then something must be wrong in my setup because it did not work for me. I tried it again and it still does not work. Anyway, I can use a list to enable the types I want to export `("TODO" "SCHD" "DEFR" "WAIT" "PROJ")`.

Comment: I am using only `#*TODO:`

Comment: Yeah, I changed that too, and it did not make a difference. Not that I understand what different it should have made.

Comment: Look at this screenshot: https://gnu.support/images/screenshots/2019-07-18/2019-18-07-16:49:55.png and I got it by setting that variable and exporting to ASCII. Maybe you export differently? I am using latest Emacs version, which version are you using?